# Comments under Post

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I created model Post and Comment, now I want to display comments from Post but I have a problem. In [tutorial](https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/homework_create_more_models/) there is a line of code in html `{% for comment in post.comments.all %}` but isn't working in my app. If I set `{% for comment in comments %}` it works but displays all comments from models (I want only comments from the post). How to fix that? Below I pasted my code.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
    short_text = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    text = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('main.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from .models import Post, Comment


def index_pl(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index_pl.html', {'posts': posts})


def single_article_pl(request, id):
    posts = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=id)
    posts.views = posts.views + 1
    posts.save()
    comments = Comment.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'single_article_pl.html', {'posts': posts, 'comments': comments})
```

html

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</div>
        <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
        <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
{% empty %}
    <p>No comments here yet :(</p>
{% endfor %}
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Comment

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Comment)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In tutorial there is a line of code in html `{% for comment in post.comments.all %}` but isn't working in my app.

This is likely because they specified the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in the `ForeignKey` from `Comment` to `Post`, like:

```
# Option 1: set the related_name to 'comments'
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        'main.Post',
        related_name='comments',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # …
```

The `related_name=…` specifies the name of the relation in *reverse*, so in this case accessing the `Comment`s of a given `Post` object. By default this is `model_name_set`, so in this case `comment_set`.

You thus can either specify a related name; or you can acces the `comment_set` manager:

```
Option 2: use the default related_name
{% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</div>
        <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
        <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
{% empty %}
    <p>No comments here yet :(</p>
{% endfor %}
```